# angular ui-typeahead Suggestions + Keep if no result

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, typeahead.js

Controller

```
 $scope.log = function(value) {
        console.log(value);
    }
 $scope.customers = array....
```

View

```
 <script type="text/ng-template" id="customPopupTemplate.html">
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" ng-show="isOpen() && !moveInProgress" ng-style="{top: position().top+'px', left: position().left+'px'}" style="display: block;" role="listbox" aria-hidden="{{!isOpen()}}">
        <li ng-repeat="match in matches track by $index" ng-class="{active: isActive($index) }" ng-mouseenter="selectActive($index)" ng-click="selectMatch($index)" role="option" id="{{::match.id}}">
            <div uib-typeahead-match index="$index" match="match" query="query" template-url="templateUrl"></div>
        </li>

        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success"  ng-click="$parent.$parent.log(query);">Post</button>
       input: {{query}}
    </ul>

</script>
     <div class="form-group">
                                <input placeholder="Vælg kunde" type="text" ng-model="customer"  typeahead-editable="false" uib-typeahead="customer as customer.customer for customer in customers | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8" class="form-control"
                                       typeahead-popup-template-url="customPopupTemplate.html"  >
                            </div>
```

When i input to typeahead, and there is no result the dropdown box disappear how can i get i to stay

also wondering on how to make typeahead auto suggestions, show when click on input box it will show dropdown with etc. first 5 in list.

Comment: `<ul>` tag is not closed

Comment: it is now, but same result

Comment: Put the `<a>` outside the `<ul>` and wrap the template in an element

Comment: Also, unless you have a directive named `whatadd`, there is no way to set a variable like that.

Comment: i dont, what is  the easiest and best way to add a variable to typeahead like this ?

Comment: also tried to call {{$parent.customer}} in template but can't get the scope ?

Comment: I'm a bit confused as there is no reference to `typeahead-popup.html` in your typeahead declaration.

Comment: sibling?  typeahead-popup.html  is the default template in the template folder

Comment: Can you be more specific about the value of the variable you want to access, and especially how it is related to the user input or to the matches according to the user input?

Comment: i want to get a list of products,   with a footer saying ( add "input" produt) with a link to a model

so if the product aint in the list user can add a new on footer link to modal

Comment: Well, the "user input" is the `query` variable of the popup isolated scope (in this scope you basically have only the "query" and the matches of that query). Try `Add {{query}}`.

Comment: @MichaelP.Bazos  updated question,  now using query like you said thx, now i just got to more questions ^^

Answer (score 0):

Directive uib-typeahead-popup has an isolated scope. This means that you cannot use any scope variables in the template, other than explicitly defined in the isolated scope of that directive.
What you want is not possible using this particular directive, unless you apply a very dirty trick, e.g. add a property to the customer object:

```
for (var i=0; i<customers.length; i++) {
    customers[i].whatadd = "something";
}
```

and then you can use the following in your template:

```
<a href="">+ add {{matches[0].whatadd}}....</a>
```

If you don't like dirty tricks, then you will have to write your own typeahead directive that does not have an isolated scope or allows you to specify the addition as an extra attribute.